# change eslint reporter file path output

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eslint

So, I'm using eslint via WSL ubuntu in VS Code (Windows).

I run the typical command `npm run lint` and everything seems to be all fine:

[image: screenshot showing stylish report over eslint with file path output being absolute]

Except that the file path which is causing errors is shown in the bash with absolute path according to WSL system (not the actual file path in Windows).

This is not convenient for my use since I can't click on the file path and got my file opened (as I used to do in other OS ;) ).

[image: screenshot proving I can't open the file erroring in vs-code due to the file path not matching windows file path]

I would like to be able to do one of these things:

- File path is shown relative to the project, in this case `src/main.ts`
- File path is show in the real windows path, in this case `C:\PATH_TO_PROJET/src/main.ts`
- Be able to tell VS-code to Substitute `/mnt/c` for `C:/`, in this case `C:\PATH_TO_PROJET/src/main.ts`

Being banging my head for really long on this one and it is time to ask for help :D

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change eslint [formatter](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/formatters/) to `codeframe` like this:

```sh
eslint --format codeframe --ext .ts ./src
```

On ubuntu inside a docker container with mounted project it print paths relative to project root. Not sure if it works on Windows/WSL too.

Example output:

```sh
warning: Missing return type on function (@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types) at src/on-connect/on-connect.ts:1:24:
> 1 | export const handler = async(event: unknown) => {
    |                        ^
  2 | 
  3 |   console.log("Event", event);
  4 |
```

Comment: What's `codeframe`? It's not listed in the eslint formatters reference you linked to.

Comment: It appears that `codeframe` used to be part of eslint 7 but is now a standalone module available on npm with the package name `eslint-formatter-codeframe`.